# Solving equation $A^TX + X^TA = B$ respect to $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, convex-optimization

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $A$ is a orthogonal matrix $(A^TA = I_n)$, how to solve the equation
$$
A^TX + X^TA = B. 
$$

Answer: If $B$ is a symmetric matrix. Then the equation has a solution and the solution is
$$
X = \frac{1}{2}AB.
$$

Comment: **Hint :** Can you first find a necessary condition on $B$ so this equation has a solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.   Do you know any related article to solve the equation?

Comment: Don't read articles and try to find the solution by yourself. Don't you see that if $B=A^TX + X^TA$, then $B$ must belong to a very well-known family of matrices ?

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I can see that $B$ is symmetrix, but how do you show that $X = \frac{AB}{2}$ is the only solution?

Comment: @Kaind Actually it is not, the OP made a mistake. The solutions are the $X = A \left(\dfrac{1}{2}B + M \right)$ where $M$ can be any skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Can you post as an answer how you arrived at that?

Comment: @Kaind I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in the comment, here is a way to solve the equation.

Let's suppose that we have a solution $X$ to the equation $A^TX+X^TA=B$. Clearly the LHS is a symmetric matrix, so $B$ has to be symmetric. Then the equation can be rewritten as
$$\dfrac{(A^TX)+(A^TX)^T}{2} = \dfrac{B}{2}$$

which leads to
$$A^TX = \dfrac{(A^TX)+(A^TX)^T}{2} +  \dfrac{(A^TX)-(A^TX)^T}{2} = \dfrac{B}{2} + M$$

where $M = \dfrac{(A^TX)-(A^TX)^T}{2}$ is skew-symmetric.

Multiplying on the left by $A$, you get finally that
$$X = A \left( \dfrac{1}{2}B + M\right)$$

Conversely, it is not difficult to check that any matrix of the type $X = A \left( \dfrac{1}{2}B + M\right)$, where $M$ is skew-symmetric, is a solution of the equation.

So there are solutions only if $B$ is symmetric, and in that case, the solutions are exactly the matrices $X = A \left( \dfrac{1}{2}B + M\right)$, where $M$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: The logic is a bit puzzling here - I can see that any matrix $X$ of the form $\frac{AB}{2} + \frac{AK}{2}$ for any skew symmetric matrix $K$ is a solution. But I don't see how you 'derived' $X$ to be that value. Instead of M let us denote it by $M(X) := \frac{(A^TX) -(A^TX)^T}{2}$ as it depends on $X$, then the equation you have got is $X = \frac{AB}{2} + A*M(X)$. How you claim that $\frac{AB}{2} + AK$ for any skew symmetric matrix $K$ is the only solution for this equation, I don't understand.

Comment: The fact that $M$ depends on $X$ is not a problem. If you define $$\mathcal{S} = \left\lbrace A \left( \dfrac{1}{2}B + M\right) \mid M \text{ is skew-symmetric} \right\rbrace$$
then the equality $X = \frac{AB}{2} + A*M(X)$ shows that $X \in \mathcal{S}$. So any solution must belong to $\mathcal{S}$. As the converse is clear, $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of all solutions.

Comment: Yep, now I understand. Nice proof.

Comment: Nice proof. But I want to explain that  $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is not a square matrix, your proof is true only when $m=n$. @TheSilverDoe

Comment: @Kadeng No, nowhere has that assumption been made in the proof.

Comment: @Kaind The conclusion is correct.  In the proof,  you multiply on the left by $A$  and use the claim that $AA^T = I_m$,  but actually, $A$ only satisfies $A^TA = I_n$.